# How to Post LinkedIn Company status update using API?

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

Is there anyway to update company status of linked in company pages via API call using PHP,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to create what LinkedIn refers to as a 'share' for a company at this point. [Here is a post on their forums](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/share-company-profile-not-personal-profile) relating to this.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29607219/682673

Answer (score 2):

This is a very quick guide. Take a look at my decision using the LinkedIn API. Have in mind that before doing that:

1. you must have a personal profile in LinkedIn;
2. your company must have a company page in LinkedIn (http://www.linkedin.com/company/yourcompanyname);
3. you must be an administrator of your company page (in order to publish updates on behalf of your company).

When the above conditions are met go to https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer and sign in with your personal profile credentials. Add a new application in order to get API Key, Secret Key, OAuth User Token and OAuth User Secret.

PHP code for LinkedIn API on your side to post company shares:

```
require 'OAuth.php'; // .. or install the PECL extension.. Google it

$apiKey = 'xxxxxxx'; // take it from your application
$apiSecret = 'yyyyyyyyy'; // take it from your application
$accessToken = 'zzzzzzzzz'; // take it from your application
$accessToken = 'kkkkkkkkkkk'; // take it from your application
$oauth = new OAuth($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$oauth->setToken($accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);

$body = new stdClass();
$body->comment = 'Some comment';
$body->content = new stdClass();
$body->content->title = 'Some title';
$body->content->description = 'Some description';
$body->content->{'submitted-url'} = 'http://www.mycompany.com/article_id/123456'; // ID of your company page in LinkedIn
$body->visibility = new stdClass();
$body->visibility->code = 'anyone';
$body_json = json_encode($body);

$oauth->fetch('http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/12345678/shares', $body_json, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, array(
  "Content-Type" => "application/json",
  "x-li-format" => "json"
));
$response = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Totally newbie question - where can I download a copy of Oauth.php?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer for this question is no longer valid and another answer linking to the announcement that it is now available has two broken links

To clarify, you *can* now post company status updates/shares and the documentation for this is located at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_share

Answer (score 1):

As of August 2013, LinkedIn's API supports sharing to company pages.

[Announcement](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/introducing-company-page-posting-and-analytics-linkedin-platform).

[Official documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/creating-company-shares).

Comment: Both links are now broken. It appears LinkedIn deleted all their historical blog posts and now have only two which go in to detail about changes to their developer program. WTG LinkedIn!